# How to kill a program if it did not produce any output in a given timeout?

Tags: bash, timeout

I want to detect when some process is stuck, but it doesn't give me any clues on the matter. All I know is that if it doesn't produce any output in a given timeout (let's say 30 seconds), it means that it's probably blocked.

I know the coreutils' `timeout` program, but it's based on the full program exit time, not on the last line of output time. I'd love if something like this worked:

```
timeout --stdout --stderr 30s my-program
```

So is there any way to do that? How can I do it?

Comment: I like the idea, but I can't point to an existing tool. This should not be hard to do per se.

Comment: You may find [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/08/monitoring-stdout-with-a-timeout/) useful.

Comment: See a distinct, simple solution at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706660/72707 (based on `inotifywait`) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The code

Save this as `tkill` (make it executable and adjust your `PATH` if needed):

```
#!/bin/bash

_terminate_children() {
        trap "exit 143" SIGTERM && kill -- "-$$"
}

trap _terminate_children SIGINT SIGTERM

tout="$1"
shift
eval "$@" | tee >(while :; do
   read -t "$tout"
   case $? in
      0) : ;;
      1) break ;;
      *) _terminate_children ;;
   esac
done)
exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

---

#### Basic usage

```
tkill 30 some_command
```

The first argument (`30` here) is the timeout in seconds.

---

#### Notes

- `tkill` expects `some_command` to generate text (not binary) output.
- `tkill` probes `stdout` of the given command. To include `stderr` redirect it like in the last advanced example below.

---

#### Advanced usage

These are valid examples:

```
tkill 9 foo -option value
tkill 9 "foo -option value"  # equivalent to the above
tkill 5 "foo | bar"
tkill 5 'foo | bar'
tkill 5 'foo | bar | baz'    # tkill monitors baz
tkill 5 'foo | bar' | baz    # baz reads from tkill
tkill 3 "foo; bar"
tkill 6 "foo && bar || baz"
tkill 7 "some_command 2>&1"
```

Use Bash syntax in these quotes.

---

#### Exit status

- If `some_command` exits by itself then its exit status will be reused as the exit status of `tkill`; `tkill 5 true` returns `0`; `tkill 5 false` returns `1`; `tkill 5 "true; false"` returns `1`.
- If the given timeout expires or `tkill` gets interrupted by `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` then the exit status will be `143`.

---

#### Fragments of code explained

- `eval` makes the advanced examples possible.
- `tee` allows us to analyze `stdin` while still passing a copy of it to `stdout`.
- `read -t` is responsible for applying the timeout, its exit status is used to determine what to do next.
- Command(s) being monitored are killed when needed with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173421).
- Exit status of monitored command(s) is retrieved with [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14276/108618).

---

#### Quirks

- `eval` makes the advanced examples possible but you need to remember it does this by evaluating its arguments. Example (somewhat artificial): if you had a file literally named `|`, then `tkill 9 ls *` would expand `*` in the current shell, `|` would appear as an argument to `eval` and it would be interpreted as a pipe operator. In this case `tkill 9 'ls *'` is better (but note it expands nothing in the current shell). It's similar with [`watch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173421) (I mean e.g. `watch ls *` vs `watch 'ls *'`).
- The evaluated command gets piped to `tee`, it does not write directly to the terminal. Some commands alter their behavior depending on whether their stdout is a terminal or not. They may colorize and/or columnize their output to a terminal, but not their output to a regular file or a pipe. E.g. `ls --color=auto` and `tkill 9 'ls --color=auto'` give different output.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp1=/tmp/tmp-$$-1
tmp2=/tmp/tmp-$$-2
touch $tmp1
touch $tmp2

time_out=30

typeset -i i

i=0
my-program > $tmp1 &
pgmpid=$!

while ps $pgmpid > /dev/null ; do
    sleep 1
    if diff $tmp1 $tmp2 > /dev/null ; then
        i=i+1
        if [ $i -gt $time_out ] ; then
            kill $pgmpid
        fi
    else
        i=0
        cp $tmp1 $tmp2 
    fi
done

rm -f $tmp1 $tmp2
```

Comment: This should do the trick, although I was expecting some kinda one-liner TBH... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Run the program in the background while copying the output to a file. After 30 seconds, if the file is empty, terminate the program, else bring it back in the foreground.

```
my-program | tee temp-file & 
sleep 30
[ -s temp-file ] && kill $! || fg $!
```

Comment: With this, if after 30 seconds it becomes frozen, you're outta luck, right?

Comment: Yeah. Seems I misunderstood the question.